# What allows for colloidal solutions of polymers to act like solutions despite the large size of polymers?

Tags: polymers, colloids

I have been introduced to a paragraph in my textbook that I am trying to understand.

> Macromolecular  colloids:  Macromolecules in  suitable
> solvents form solutions in which the size of the macromolecules
> may be in the colloidal range. Such systems are called
> macromolecular  colloids.  These  colloids  are  quite  stable  and
> resemble true solutions in many respects. Examples of naturally
> occurring  macromolecules  are  starch,  cellulose,  proteins  and
> enzymes; and those of man-made macromolecules are polythene,
> nylon, polystyrene, synthetic rubber, etc

Upon some further research I did, 'macromolecule' is another term  used to refer to polymers as stated in the below paragraph from the same book.

> The term polymer is defined as very large molecules having
> high molecular mass (10^3-10^7u). These are also referred
> to as macromolecules, which are formed by joining of
> repeating structural units on a large scale. The repeating
> structural  units  are  derived  from  some  simple  and
> reactive molecules known as monomers and are linked
> to  each  other  by  covalent  bonds.

As far as I have been taught, the principle factor that decides whether a particle in a dispersion medium (such as water) is a solution, colloid or suspension, is its particle size. Bigger the particle size, the less heterogeneous the mixture, and thus the more like suspensions they behave

However, for one, from a bit of research I did, polymer chain lengths range anywhere from 1 nm all the way to much beyond 1 micro meter

With that on hand, what I have seen about solutions is that the particle size ranges from 0.01 to 1 nm, usually consisting of ions and small molecules. According to my book, macromolecular colloids are relatively stable and behave like solutions. How do they remain stable and form psuedo-solutions despite their very large size?

Comment: That they aren't "very large". Chain length is only one dimension and polymers form [random coils](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_coil).

Comment: @Mithoron So what dimension should be considered when we have to see how soluble a particle is? Is it the area, or perhaps the volume?